# Calendar Icon not appearing using Angular Material. md-datepicker directive

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

My code.

`<md-datepicker ng-model="csv.date" md-placeholder="Search Date"></md-datepicker>`

The icon will not appear, but something is there when I inspect the dom. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

**Check the following code and take what all you need. Thank you.**

```html
<html lang="en" >
   <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.css">
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.0/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>
      <style>
         .datepickerdemo md-content {
            padding-bottom: 200px; 
         }
        .datepickerdemo {
            font-size: 11px;
            color: darkred;
            margin: 10px 0 0 25px; 
         }
      </style>
      <script>
         angular
            .module('firstApplication', ['ngMaterial'])

                   
      </script>      
   </head>
   <body ng-app="firstApplication"> 
   <h4>Choose the date</h4>
      <div class="datepickerdemo"  layout="column" ng-cloak>
         <md-content>
           <md-datepicker ng-model="csv.date" md-placeholder="Select Date"></md-datepicker>
         </md-content>
    </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the code, Alexis. I've pulled the parts out that I didn't have and the icon still does not show. I don't get it.